# How to get php key as value in php array

Tags: php, arrays, function, key, output

I am having an array like this..

```
 Array
    (
        [a] => 100%
        [b] => 0%
        [c] => 0%
        [d] => 0%
    )
```

I want to change this as

```
Array
(
    [0] => a,100%
    [1] => b,0%
    [2] => c,0%
    [3] => d,0%
)
```

Is it possible in php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `foreach` will do..

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
{
    $new_arr[]=$k.",".$v;
}
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](https://eval.in/147463)</kbd>

Comment: Micro-comparison time! [Yours](https://eval.in/147476) is ever so slightly faster than [mine](https://eval.in/147475)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps...

```
$newArray = array_map(function($k, $v) {
    return sprintf('%s,%s', $k, $v);
}, array_keys($array), $array);
```

Demo - http://ideone.com/Pc0cdC

Comment: Nice one phil ! You are always different from the rest of the herd :P

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I just like using closures, working in JS for most of my day has done that to me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
   $newarr[]=$key.",".$value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get keys of this array you can use [`array_keys()`](http://www.php.net/array_keys) function

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$array = array(0 => 100, "color" => "red");
print_r(array_keys($array));
```

?>

```
Output : 

Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => color
)
```

May be this ..